# SetNull in Python script for Arcgis assign 0 value

Tags: arcpy, geotiff-tiff, nodata

I am writing a script in Python where I assign to few Tiff defined in a function as inputRaster a NoData value as follows:

```
whereClauseSetNull = "VALUE > 100"
outSetNull = SetNull(inputRaster, inputRaster, whereClauseSetNull)
outSetNull.save(outSetNullFullPath)
```

When I add the resulting Tiff to ArcMap, the pixels that meet the condition have a 0 value. Only if I manually assign the 0 value to NoData they are recognized as such.

Even more strange, if I manually repeat the process through the Set Null Tool, the result is what I expected.

Can anybody know why SetNull function assign 0 instead of NoData to the pixels that meet the conditions when executed on the script?

Comment: I think it is something about the way TIFF handles NoData. I found this link that could help ... http://coast.noaa.gov/geozone/troubles-tiff-no-data-values-floating-point/ 

Is your output using the "Set Null" tool TIFF output?

Comment: A colleague of mine has been having trouble with nodata in tif files since we upgraded to 10.2.2. As you zoom in the nodata turns black. We thought it was a pyramid issue but after a bit of fiddling around we decided it was to do with the nodata and the default value that it had. By exporting it to ASCII then back into a tiff and setting it to -9999 the display of it behaved.

Comment: Could you please specify ArcGIS version and attach an input raster example.